# Proof that $\mathbb R$ excluding countable set is bijective to all reals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that $\mathbb{R}\setminus C\sim\mathbb{R}$ where $C$ is a countable set. I have done the proof for $\mathbb{R}\sim\mathbb{R}\cup C$ but am running into issues where natural numbers may be finite in either of the sets for the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the reals are uncountable we can find another countable set in $\mathbb{R}-C$ let this set be called $D$. We let all of $\mathbb{R}-(C\cup D)$  get sent to themselves then we have to map $(C\cup D)$ to$D$. But we can do this easily in the same fashion we made a bijection from the integers to the naturals since both C and D like the negative and non negatives of the integers are disjoint and countable we can send the union of any two disjoint countable sets to a countable set through a bijection